# how can put space between two button in OnsenUI

Tags: onsen-ui, monaca

i unable to put space between two button . and i also tried without `ons-row` and `ons-col`

code :

```
<ons-template id="page2.html">
    <ons-page>
        <ons-row>
            <ons-col >
                <ons-button id="show-loading" type="button" class="button button--large" ng-click="showLoading()">Show
                    Loading
                </ons-button>
            </ons-col>
        </ons-row>
        <ons-row>
            <ons-col >
                <ons-button id="uniqueDeviceShow" type="button" class="button button--large"
                            ng-click="uniqueDeviceShow()">Unique Device ID
                </ons-button>
            </ons-col>
        </ons-row>
        <ons-row>
            <ons-col >
                <ons-button id="barcodeScan" type="button" class="button button--large" ng-click="barcodeScan()">Barcode
                    Scan
                </ons-button>
            </ons-col>
        </ons-row>
        <ons-row>
            <ons-col >
                <ons-button id="fileMake" type="button" class="button button--large" ng-click="fileMake()">File Make
                </ons-button>
            </ons-col>
        </ons-row>
        <ons-row>
            <ons-col >
                <ons-button id="fileUpload" type="button" class="button button--large" ng-click="fileUpload()">File
                    Upload
                </ons-button>
            </ons-col>
        </ons-row>


        <ons-modal var="modal">
            <ons-icon icon="ion-load-c" spin="true"></ons-icon>
            <br><br>
            Please wait.<br>Loading...
        </ons-modal>

    </ons-page>
</ons-template>
```

Here is my OnsenUI

[image]

I try to do something like this ionic UI
[image]

**Note : if i use `<br>`then ui button space between two button ok fine it is working well in iOS but not android . what should i do ?**

Comment: Just use CSS, such as padding-top:10px;

Comment: @Munsterlander yea i done it by CSS

Comment: @twilight2 - Onsen does not provide a special modifier for such paddings|margins, so Munsterlander's suggestion is currently the best option.